# problem in writing number in csv file using python

Tags: python, csv

I have this array of strings:

```
my_array = ['5.0', '6.066', '7.5', '7.83', '9.75']
```

and I want to write first 3 items on my csv file.

I am using this code

```
n=0
with open("file.csv",'w',newline="",)as e:
    while n<3:
        writer=csv.writer(e)    
        writer.writerow(my_array[n])
        n=n+1
```

The output is:

```
5,.,0
6,.,0,6,6
7,.,5
```

but I don't want to separate numbers with comma
for example the output must be:

```
5.0
6.066
7.5
```

What should I do?

Comment: Try regex, in which you search for ',', and replace it with empty space ''.

Comment: @DennisKozevnikoff or just don't write commas in the first place.

Comment: `writerow()` wants an iterable, and each element of that iterable is written as one column of the csv. Because a string is an iterable, each element (character) of that string is written to a separate column. To fix this, pass a _list_ to `writerow()` that only contains your single string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does csvwriter.writerow() put a comma after each character?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1816880/why-does-csvwriter-writerow-put-a-comma-after-each-character)

Answer (score 2):

`writerow()` wants an iterable, and each element of that iterable is written as one column of the csv. Because a string is an iterable, each element (character) of that string is written to a separate column. To fix this, pass a *list* to `writerow()` that only contains your single string

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

my_array=['5.0', '6.066', '7.5', '7.83', '9.75']

with open('example.csv', 'w+') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for elm in my_array[:3]:
        writer.writerow([elm])
```

Output of `example.csv`:

```
5.0
6.066
7.5
```

Comment: An answer with an explanation is **always** better than an answer that says "do this". [answer]

Comment: @PranavHosangadi You're right. Thanks for your edit.

Comment: While this is the correct use of the `csv` module, for a single column it is overkill.

Comment: @MarkTolonen You're right. The OP can simply iterate over the list and write each element separated by a return line.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you don't actually want a CSV (**comma separated** values) file, so don't use the `csv` module.

Simply write each string from the list to a separate line in the file.

Some options are:

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    for value in my_array[:3]:
        print(value, file=f)
```

```
with open("file.txt", "w") as f:
    f.write("\n".join(my_array[:3]))
```